# Its there a way to add a custom filter dialog to a column header in the table API provided by MudBlazor

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Im looking for documentation for a clear proper way to
add/reder a custom filter dialog to a column header in a table from MudBlazor component interface

Basically Im interested in how to render and hook actions like in the column header that allow me to filter using common queries like
Equals
Not Equals
Or
Contains
[image]